# Rendering the view returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've got a collection view with two filter methods, and a render method which takes a parameter. The problem I'm stuck with is that when rendering the view for the first time it returns me an error. Here's my collection:

```
var ResumeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    filterActive: function () {
        var active = this.where({interviewed: false});
        return new ResumeCollection(active);
    },
    filterInterviewed: function () {
        var interviewed = this.where({interviewed: true});
        return new ResumeCollection(interviewed);
    }
});
```

And my view:

```
var ResumeList = Backbone.View.extend({
    events { // hash array of filter events },
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    render: function (filtered) {
        var self = this;
        var data;

        if (!filtered) {
            data = this.collection.toArray(); 
        } else {
            data = filtered.toArray();
        }

        _.each(data, function (cv) {
            self.$el.append((new ResumeView({model: cv})).render().$el);
        });

        return this;
    },

    showActive: function (ev) {
        var filtered = this.collection.filterActive();
        this.render(filtered);
    },

    showInterviewed: function (ev) {
        var filtered = this.collection.filterInterviewed();
        this.render(filtered);
    },

    showAll: function (ev) {
        this.render(this.collection);
    }
});
```

This view gets rendered for the first time in my router by passing a collection:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'home'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.layout = new LayoutView();
    }

    home: function () {
        this.layout.render(new ResumeList({
            collection: new ResumeCollection()
        }));
    }
});
```

And this is the layout view within which all the other views are rendered:

```
var LayoutView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#outlet'),
    render: function (view) {
        if (this.child && this.child !== view) {
            this.child.undelegateEvents();
        }

        this.child = view;
        this.child.setElement(this.$el).render();
        return this;
    }
});
```

When I just refresh my page, I get `filtered.toArray is not a function` error and nothing is rendered respectively. After inspecting everything in the debugger, I found out that when the view gets rendered for the first time, the `filtered` attribute receives an empty collection, assigns it to `data` variable, which becomes an empty array and goes to the body of `render` function, becoming `undefined` after that. The mysteries go here: whenever I click items, that are bound to my `show*` events, they act exactly as expected and render either models where `interviewed === false`, or `true` or the whole collection. This looks kinda magic to me and I haven't got the faintest idea what can I do with that.

**ADDED**: [GitHub repo with this project](https://github.com/AlexNikolaev94/hr-dashboard)

Comment: Can you attach the last few lines of the call stack from the debugger? Also you aren't including the code which shows how this ResumeList get rendered first. Your `showAll` function passed `this.collection` where I'm guess the better behaviour would be to pass nothing and rely on the logic inside render to choose the default which is `this.collection`. One last thing - `var data = (filtered || this.collection).toArray()` - slightly less verbose?

Comment: That leads to more questions, it doesn't show any call to `render()`

Comment: @mikeapr4 I've got a `layout` view that renders others like his child views

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4gyne5ev/ - this works, what's different?

Comment: @mikeapr4 everything's the same, so that's kinda magic.

Comment: It's got to be whatever the `this.layout.render` function does, it must pass a parameter to `render`, and that where you get the `filtered.toArray` not being a function.

Comment: @mikeapr4 I've provided a layout view with render function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a piece of advice from my mentor I realized that the core of the problem was in asynchronous origin of `fetch` method -- as I passed `this.collection.fetch` in my initialize function, it executed after my `render` method, not before it, so my `render` method had just nothing to render when the view was called for the first time. So, this fix worked:

```
var ResumeList = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
         this.collection = options.collection();
         // removed .fetch() method from here
    },
    render: function (filtered) {
        var self = this;
        var data;
        // and added it here:
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function (collection) {
                if (!filtered) {
                    data = collection.toArray();
                } else {
                    data = filtered.toArray();
                }
                self.$el.html(self.template(collection.toJSON()));
                _.each(data, function (cv) {
                   self.$el.append((new ResumeView({model: cv})).render().$el);
               })
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And this worked perfectly and exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `home` function on the `AppRouter` has a typo. You have an extra semi-colon.

```
home: function () {
    this.layout.render(new ResumeList({
        collection: new ResumeCollection();
    }));
}
```

Should be

```
home: function () {
    this.layout.render(new ResumeList({
        collection: new ResumeCollection()
    }));
}
```

I needed to remove it to get the JSFiddle working: https://jsfiddle.net/4gyne5ev/1/

I'd recommend adding some kind of linting tool into your IDE or Build process (http://eslint.org/)

Comment: well that was a typo in my question, I've double checked my code and it seemed to be without such typos, but it doesn't work anyways. I can provide a link to github, if it would help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add home url content to your db.json file like this

```
"" : [
    {
       'somthing': 'somthing'
    }
]
```

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't help :(

Comment: Please can u just console log (self.collection) and tell me the response?

Comment: Now please try  to console log( self.collection.filterActive());

Comment: the same thing :(

Comment: Than you need use backbone collection  parse function instead of  filterActive or filterInterviewed

Comment: and please check your beckend it seams that your rest url is not working

Comment: backend works fine, because when I click my buttons, it does return me the items from the collection that I need

Comment: please change this if it dont work i just give up :(

Comment: make url attribute to method

Comment: url: function(){
    return 'your url'
}

Comment: inside my `render` function?

Comment: no in your collection change url:'http://localhost:3000' to url: fucntion(){return 'http://localhost:3000'}

Comment: and please give me git

Comment: that didn't help, link to github is in my question

Comment: plz try to change this i just see this filtered.toArray() change  to filtered. filterActive().toArray() f

Comment: the same thing :(

Comment: How i understand u need to add "" for your home url in ur db.json file 
"":[{},{},{}] and it will show ur home page with your content i make it work

Comment: can you please write that  in your answer, so that I could accept it?

Comment: i have change answer

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't help either way

Comment: can you plz tell me what server you are running for your frontend and plz upload some pictures of your working pages

Comment: what u need to display in home page?

Comment: Now i can see only 1 resume in home page C++ developer Gwynyth Llewellyn